# ESXi 6.0 PXE boot

Tags: esxi, pxe

i try to provision a ESXi 6.0 server with Foreman.
The networking configuration and the stuff above work's fine.
But after the reboot SSh and ESX Shell is not enabled.
Any idea's how to fix this?
Even simple cat & echo commands are not working.

```
vmaccepteula

keyboard 'German'
rootpw --iscrypted somestringhere

install --firstdisk --overwritevmfs --novmfsondisk

<% subnet = @host.subnet -%>
network --bootproto=static --ip=<%= @host.ip %> --netmask=<%= subnet.mask %> --gateway=<%= subnet.gateway %> --nameserver=<%= subnet.dns_primary %> --device=<%= @host.mac %> --hostname=<%= @host %>

### At this point nothing happens -> SSH or ESX Shell is not enabled ###
%firstboot --interpreter=busybox

vim-cmd hostsvc/enable_ssh
vim-cmd hostsvc/start_ssh

vim-cmd hostsvc/enable_esx_shell
vim-cmd hostsvc/start_esx_shell

sleep 30
reboot
```

Answer (score 0):

For example this:

```
vmaccepteula 
install --firstdisk --overwritevmfs 
rootpw q1w2e3r4
reboot


#network configuration 
network --bootproto=dhcp --device=<%= @host.mac %>

# run the following command only on the firstboot
%firstboot --interpreter=busybox


# enable & start remote ESXi Shell (SSH)
vim-cmd hostsvc/enable_ssh
vim-cmd hostsvc/start_ssh

# enable & start ESXi Shell (TSM)
vim-cmd hostsvc/enable_esx_shell
vim-cmd hostsvc/start_esx_shell
```

is causing a loop